# Counting Distinct users over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Data is thus:

```
Date       | userid 
-------------------
01/01/2016 | jacby
01/01/2016 | jacby
01/01/2016 | donta
01/01/2016 | stapf
02/02/2016 | kamed
02/02/2016 | jacby
02/02/2016 | kamed
02/02/2016 | carpi
03/03/2016 | slwig
03/03/2016 | kamed
```

What I would like to be able to do is produce an output, using SQL, TSQL or SSRS expressions, that looks like:

```
Date       | Unique Users
-----------------------------
01/01/2016 | 3
02/02/2016 | 5
03/03/2016 | 6
```

which is essentially a running total of unique users, in reference to unique users up to that date.  I.e. from a start day, i want to know the total number of unique users since the start date, ongoing.

I can do a running total of unique users on a particular day, but that doesn't account for if that user had logged in on a previous day.  I did wonder about a while loop using the date as a counter, but really, I don't know where to start with that.

My google-fu is way off and I can't think of the correct terminology to describe what I am looking for.

**EDIT - Apologies - there may be more than one entry per day for each user.  I have amended the source example table above.**

Comment: according to you what should be the output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get the *first* time someone signed up and then take a cumulative sum of this value:

```
select
  t.date,
  sum(
    sum(
      case
        when seqnum = 1 then 1
        else 0
      end
    )
  ) over (
    order by
      date
  ) as numUniques
from
  (
    select
      t.*,
      row_number() over (
        partition by user
        order by
          date
      ) as seqnum
    from
      t
  ) t
group by
  t.date
order by
  t.date
```

You can put a `where` clause in the subquery to restrict this to a particular set of dates.

Comment: Thanks for this - very very close, but please take a look at my edit above...sorry for the confusion

Comment: @BenjiBoyWick . . . More than one entry per day doesn't matter.  This should still work -- unless you want to count the user multiple times on that day.

Comment: Ok - thanks for that, SQL Server 2012 is complaining that 'seqnum' isn't in the GROUP BY clause. I can add it, but the results don't look convincing - i.e. multiple lines per date.

Comment: @BenjiBoyWick . . . It was missing an additional `sum()`.  The `sum()`with a `case` gets the number of customers who start on each day.  The `sum(sum())` gets the cumulative number.  I'll note in passing that this should be much, much better performance-wise than a correlated subquery.

Comment: That's the one - brilliant - nice solution.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    MyDate date
    , UserID varchar(10)
)

insert #Something (MyDate, UserID) values
('01/01/2016', 'jacby'),
('01/01/2016', 'donta'),
('01/01/2016', 'stapf'),
('02/02/2016', 'kamed'),
('02/02/2016', 'jacby'),
('02/02/2016', 'carpi'),
('03/03/2016', 'slwig'),
('03/03/2016', 'kamed')

select distinct s.MyDate
    , 
    (
        select count(distinct UserID)
        from #Something s2
        where s2.MyDate <= s.MyDate
    ) as UniqueUsers
from #Something s
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give the required output :-

```
declare @table_name table
(Date date NOT NULL,
userid varchar(20) NOT NULL)

Insert into @table_name
values('01/01/2016','jacby'),
('01/01/2016','donta'),
('01/01/2016','stapf'),
('02/02/2016','kamed'),
('02/02/2016','jacby'),
('02/02/2016','carpi'),
('03/03/2016','slwig'),
('03/03/2016','kamed')



select distinct Date,
(select count(distinct userid) from @table_name TM where TM.Date<=TN.Date) [Unique Users]
from @table_name TN
```

**Output** :

```
  Date      Unique Users
2016-01-01      3
2016-02-02      5
2016-03-03      6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select d2.date, count(distinct d2.userid) 
  from data d1 
  join data d2 
        on d2.date <= d1.date 
 group by d2.date
```